# Bootloader questions in assembly

Tags: memory, assembly, kernel, bootloader

I have an interesting question, I was trying to make a simple bootloader that would boot and display text. As I did further research, I discovered that the bootloader needed to reserve memory for something. Here are my questions:

1. How do you reserve memory for the bootloader?
2. Why do you need to reserve memory?
3. What other functions does a bootloader need to preform.
4. How do I pass control to the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to "reserve" memory, rather just use it.

Really though, you need this because your kernel expects to be at the start of addressable memory. For that reason, the first thing you should do is to copy the bootloader, which will probably be running from the MBR at this point, into high memory (way past where the kernel will be), then jump to it. You then need to load the kernel into the start of memory, set up the rest of the environment for the kernel (again, it will expect certain things, like the Linux kernel command line, to be at specific places in memory), then jump to its entry point.

When you have gotten here, you don't care about the bootloader any more, it's purpose in life is done. Control has been passed to the kernel, and it will probably overwrite the section of RAM used for your loader at some point.

This might also help to get your head around the early stages of the boot process: [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linuxboot/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but one problem I've been having is that I don't know how to jump to a place in memory (or copy to a place in memory).

Comment: I'm not entirely versed in x86 assembler, but `jmp xyz` will allow you to jump to address xyz. To copy memory, you'll need to word-by-word load a word into a register, then write it to another memory address. [this page](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/blockcopy.html) also seems to detail the implementation of a quick memcpy in assembler.

Comment: Actually, ignore me, I've just realised you'll be doing this in C instead. Jumping to an arbitrary place in memory can be done with jmp, as before, you'll just have to wrap it in a `__asm__` block. Memory copy can be done with memcpy, just passing in a memory address instead of a pointer, since they're basically the same thing. You could well have to drop to writing assembler at some point to get the desired result though.

Comment: @JAW1025: learn to program in x86 assembly language. Do it well and before going into bootloader/kernel programming. Without the knowledge it will be unbearably hard to write such low level things. Start with simpler things.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will learn x86 assembly a bit better, and thanks for the help for making it in c.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind every modern PC still boots in 16-bit (called *real mode*). Hence, your boot loader will have to use 16-bit code. One of the first things a bootloader does, after having loaded the first stage of the kernel, is to switch to 32-bit mode (called *protected mode*).

The first think you should do is to become familiar with the 16-bit PC architecture and especially its segmentation model. You'll need it to understand how to write the first part of the bootloader in 16-bit mode.
Next, you'll need to understand the i386 architecture (32-bit mode) in order to switch to protected mode and configure the segment registers, paging, etc.

Keep in mind the BIOS code is 16-bit code only usable when the CPU is in 16-bit mode (real mode) through software interrupts. Once you switch to protected mode, you can't use it anymore (unless you switch back to 16-bit mode which is cumbersome).
A good reference to the BIOS' interrupts is Ralf Brown's Interrupt List: http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm

In terms of kernel development, a good tutorial to start writing an OS for x86 from scratch is James Molloy's Kernel Development Tutorial: http://raw.knusbaum.com/jamesmolloy/tutorial_html/

He uses GRUB to load his kernel which is probably the best thing to do since GRUB already switches the CPU to protected mode and setup a GDT for you. It then becomes much simpler to load a simple kernel in C.

If you decide to not use GRUB and write everything yourself, you'll have to use 16-bit code to load your kernel using software interrupts from the BIOS (see ref. above). Also, if you want your kernel to be in the ELF format, you'll have to write an ELF loader.
Keep in mind that the bootsector loaded by the BIOS is exactly 512 byte long. That's very little code (actually 510 bytes since the last 2 are for the boot signature). That's why bootsectors load a 2nd stage bootloder that doesn't have this size constraint.

Anyway, good luck in your endeavor!

Comment: The problem is that the GRUB spec makes it quite clear that you should set up your own GDT. The [spec states](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html): _GDTR’
Even though the segment registers are set up as described above, **the ‘GDTR’ may be invalid**, so the OS image must not load any segment registers (even just reloading the same values!) until it sets up its own ‘GDT’._

Comment: Agreed. However, you can setup your GDT later in your C code which is much more convenient and readable (provided you wrote some asm function that calls the lgdt instruction).

Comment: *Keep in mind every modern PC still boots in 16-bit (called real mode)* Not exactly.  Modern PCs use UEFI firmware that switches to 32 or 64-bit mode soon after booting.  (And the power-on state isn't exactly real mode, it's kind of unreal mode with a high CS base).  Dropping back to 16-bit real mode to run a legacy BIOS bootloader is an optional thing a PC's firmware can do if configured to do so.  Along with emulating a bunch of hardware that doesn't really exist.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding answer to your Question 1

1) Just go to linker file of your project and you can do something like below.

2) Make sure to also move your Reset vector along with your vector table.

```
    MEMORY
    {
    /*  ------------------- BOOT LOADER CODE --------------------------------------*/
        BOOT_cached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 32K-0x40
        BOOT_uncached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0C000000, LENGTH = 32K-0x40

    /*  ------------------- USB INTERFACE -----------------------------------------*/
        USB_INTERFACE_cached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08007FC0, LENGTH = 0x40
        USB_INTERFACE_uncached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0C007FC0, LENGTH = 0x40

    /*  ------------------- APPLICATION CODE ------------------------------------- */
    /*  APP_cached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08008000, LENGTH = 256K-32K */
    /*  APP_uncached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0C008000, LENGTH = 256K-32K */

    /*  PSRAM_1(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFFC000, LENGTH = 0x4000 */
    /*  DSRAM_1_system(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x8000 */
    /*  DSRAM_2_comm(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x20008000, LENGTH = 0x8000 */
    /*  SRAM_combined(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFFC000, LENGTH = 0x14000 */

        DSRAM_1_system(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x2000D000, LENGTH = 0x3000
        SRAM_combined(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x2000D000, LENGTH = 0x3000
    }

    stack_size = DEFINED(stack_size) ? stack_size : 4096;
    no_init_size = 64;
```

3) Also ,you can confirm if your vector table is at right address by checking your project output.lst file as below.

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .usb_interface 00000024  08007fc0  0c007fc0  0000ffc0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .text         000050f0  08000000  0c000000  00008000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 Stack         00001000  2000d000  2000d000  00015000  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .data         00000050  2000e000  0c0050f0  0000e000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  4 .bss          000006a8  2000e050  0c005140  0000e050  2**2
                  ALLOC
  5 USB_RAM       00000e00  2000e6f8  2000e6f8  00015000  2**2
```